# Write to log in Azure Function

Tags: azure, function, ilogger

This is the guts of the code I have. I want to write to the log to troubleshoot. It does not like it in the other methods. I saw some examples where they discussed how to achieve this but no real code I could find to try.

I'm writing an Azure function from within the portal.

Any assistance most appreciated.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   bool isGood = Verify(myKey, myInput;

   return code != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Request Successful")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Bad Request");

} // End Main

public static bool Verify(String key, String input)

    {

        log.LogInformation("Write something here");

    return;

    }

    private static string CreateToken(string message, string secret)

    {
        log.LogInformation("Write something here");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to log? It's not clear in your question, and there are samples in your code (log.LogInformation("Write something here");

Comment: Sorry. The last two do not work. It only works in the main part where it is handling the http request. The function is to handle a github webhook. If I don't have the log statement in Verify or CreateToken it works fine. If I have a log statement like the one in the code it fails and sends back a 500. Not sure where else to check for the possible problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass ILogger to your methods assign it to a static variable in the Run method:

option 1:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   bool isGood = Verify(myKey, myInput, log);
   var token = CreateToken("abc","def",log);

   return code != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Request Successful")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Bad Request");

} // End Main

public static bool Verify(String key, String input, ILogger log)

    {

        log.LogInformation("Write something here");

    return true;

    }

    private static string CreateToken(string message, string secret, ILogger log)

    {
        log.LogInformation("Write something here");
        return "";
    }
```

option 2:

```
public static class Function1
{
   private static ILogger _log = null;
   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
   {
    _log = log;
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   bool isGood = Verify(myKey, myInput;

   return code != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Request Successful")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Bad Request");

} // End Main

public static bool Verify(String key, String input)

    {

        _log.LogInformation("Write something here");

    return true;

    }

    private static string CreateToken(string message, string secret)

    {
        _log.LogInformation("Write something here");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static ILogger at the class level, assign it in one of the Azure Functions invoked methods, and then use it in your other classes.

```
public static class LogTest
{
    static ILogger _log;

    [FunctionName("LogTest")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        _log = log;
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        LogIt("Log this");

        return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Done logging");
    }

    private static void LogIt(string s)
    {
        _log.LogInformation(s);
    }
}
```